# Populate values for categorical data in their respective one-hot encoded columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, one-hot-encoding

I have an csv file which have 100s of columns and rows.
There two columns are my interest and based on that I need to create new columns in that csv file.
Example:
I have interested columns as below,
input.csv

```
 count  description    
    1   Good        
    2   Medium          
    2   Best        
    1   Worst       
    2   Worst       
    1   Medium      
    9   Good
```

Output I expected,
output.csv

```
 count  description    Good  Medium  Best  Worst
    1   Good            1     0       0      0
    2   Medium          0     2       0      0
    2   Best            0     0       2      0
    1   Worst           0     0       0      1
    2   Worst           0     0       0      1
    1   Medium          0     1       0      0
    9   Good            9     0       0      0
```

In the above csv table, based on the values of 'count' and 'description'.
 I am creating new columns Good,Medium,Best,Worst (from description values) and fill the values from count and put null to unavailable values of that row.
I tried with compare the columns and map the value,but not able to put the value properly in the new columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `str.get_dummies`

For performance and succinctness, use `str.get_dummies` with broadcasted numpy multiplication.

```
v = df['description'].str.get_dummies()
df.join(pd.DataFrame(
    v.values * df['count'].values[:, None], columns=v.columns))


   count description  Best  Good  Medium  Worst
0      1        Good     0     1       0      0
1      2      Medium     0     0       2      0
2      2        Best     2     0       0      0
3      1       Worst     0     0       0      1
4      2       Worst     0     0       0      2
5      1      Medium     0     0       1      0
6      9        Good     0     9       0      0
```

> I now see this is a slightly different version of [@nixon's
>   answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53816582/4909087), but hopefully
>   the difference in how broadcasting is performed should excuse me :-)

---

#### `pivot` and `fillna`

Or, a modified version of OP's `pivot` solution:

```
df.join(df.reset_index()
          .pivot(index='index', columns='description', values='count')
          .fillna(0, downcast='infer'))

   count description  Best  Good  Medium  Worst
0      1        Good     0     1       0      0
1      2      Medium     0     0       2      0
2      2        Best     2     0       0      0
3      1       Worst     0     0       0      1
4      2       Worst     0     0       0      2
5      1      Medium     0     0       1      0
6      9        Good     0     9       0      0
```

Answer (score 2):

A way to do it is to create dummy columns using [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html), and [`multiply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.multiply.html) them with `df['count]` to get the desired output:

```
d = pd.get_dummies(df.description) 
df.assign(**d.multiply(df['count'], axis=0))

    count description  Best  Good  Medium  Worst
0      1        Good     0     1       0      0
1      2      Medium     0     0       2      0
2      2        Best     2     0       0      0
3      1       Worst     0     0       0      1
4      2       Worst     0     0       0      2
5      1      Medium     0     0       1      0
6      9        Good     0     9       0      0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pivot and add original frame:

```
f = df.pivot(columns='description', values='count').fillna(value=0, downcast='infer')
df[['count', 'description']].merge(f, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Which results in:

```
   count description  Best  Good  Medium  Worst
0      1        Good     0     1       0      0
1      2      Medium     0     0       2      0
2      2        Best     2     0       0      0
3      1       Worst     0     0       0      1
4      2       Worst     0     0       0      2
5      1      Medium     0     0       1      0
6      9        Good     0     9       0      0
```

Answer (score 1):

thank you for the above answers.
I also tried and the solution as follows,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/input.csv')
res = df.pivot(index='index', columns='description', values='count')
res.to_csv('/out.csv',',',dtype='unicode8')
res1 = res.replace('NaN', '0', regex=True)
res1.to_csv('/out1.csv',',',dtype='unicode8')
```

Thanks,
Sundar